# How to combine wildcard(s) with environment variable in search?

Tags: yq

Is it possible to use an environment variable with wildcards in a query?

Given:

```
LevelA:
  levelB:
    - sometexthere
    - other.value.here
```

The following query:

```
yq eval '.LevelA.levelB.[] | select(. == "*text*")' $file
```

returns: `sometexthere`.

An environment variable can also be used:

```
A="sometexthere" yq eval '.LevelA.levelB.[] | select(. == env(A) )' $file
```

to return the same value: `sometexthere`.  However, this is a little pointless since the output is identical to the input variable value.

If wildcards are combined with the environment variable (to match a partial string), the command returns nothing:

```
A=text yq eval '.LevelA.levelB.[] | select(. == "*env(A)*")' $file
```

Is there another way possible to search with yq for a partial string using an environment variable?

Comment: I don't think yq supports this too. You could take it up with the author though. The jq DSL, that the author is using to adopt for yq v4 supports `test`/`startswith` functions. You could ask the author as a feature request!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need the `env()` operator to achieve this. Instead, use single quote to concatenate shell variables in your query.

```
A="text"
yq eval '.LevelA.levelB.[] | select(. == "*'$A'*" )' file.yml
```

output:

```
sometexthere
```

With this technique, you can leverage bash [parameter-expansions](https://devhints.io/bash#parameter-expansions).

I have added `text with space` to the `levelB` to demonstrate.

```
# file.yml
LevelA:
  levelB:
    - sometexthere
    - other.value.here
    - text with space
```

Given the variable `A="without space"`, use substitution `${A/out/}` to remove the first occurrence of the string `"out"`. The `select` operator will now search for the wildcard
string `"*with space*"`.

```
A="without space"    
yq eval '.LevelA.levelB.[] | select(. == "*'"${A/out/}"'*" )' file.yml
#       |                                | ||     |   || |  |
#       |                                | ||     |   || |  └> (a.1) end yq query
#       |                                | ||     |   || └> (b) end string
#       |                                | ||     |   |└> (a.2) open yq query (end concat)
#       |                                | ||     |   └> (c) bash double quote
#       |                                | ||     └> remove the first occurent of "out"
#       |                                | |└> (c) bash double quote
#       |                                | └> (a.2) close yq query (begin concat)
#       |                                └> (b) begin string
#       └> (a.1) start yq query
```

output:

```
text with space
```

Comment: jpmorin, thank you for your reply and feedback!  Your tip on using single quotes to insert a bash variable is a great solution!  Note that in the first code snippet you gave, a semi-colon should be added so that the `A="text"` assignment happens as a bash command.  Otherwise, `A` is not assigned as a bash variable, only as a yq variable, and yq returns all values.  At least that's what I experienced - let me know if you get something different.  If you agree, please update and I'll mark this as accepted.

Comment: jabberwocky, You are absolutely right about that missing semi-colon. I tested it with a multiline script and then flattened it to answer. I changed it to a multiline script and separate output for readability. Thank you!